# Accessing nested objects in JSP View

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, el

I have a list of Objects. The object is of the following class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "userid" ,unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String id;
    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="phone_user", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userid")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="phoneid")})
    private List<Phone> phones;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public List<Phone> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }
    public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
    }





}
```

In my controller method I add this list to the model as:

```
model.addAttribute("lists",phone.getUsers());
```

In my JSP I am unable to access the lists getter methods. I need to access the getId and the getFirstName getters. 
This is my JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${lists}" var="listvalue">
    <tr>
        <td>Employee ID: <c:out value="${listvalue}"/></td>
        <td>Employee Pass: <c:out value="${listvalue.getId()}"/></td>  
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I get the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/phoneview.jsp at line 33
```

line 33 is :

```
<td>Employee Pass: <c:out value="${listvalue.getId()}"/></td>
```

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of invoking method `getId()` you should use JavaBean style property:

```
<c:out value="${listvalue.id}"/>
```

It should work because EL (Expression Language) uses JavaBeans specification. In terms of this specification `listvalue` is a Java bean and `id` is a property which is read by getter method `getId()`.

**See also:** [EL Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: JSP Expression Language uses JavaBeans specification. In terms of this specification `listvalue` is a Java bean and `id` is a property which is read by getter method getId().